# Subsetting on pandas dataframe after using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, subset

I would like to subset the following DataFrame *after* pivoting the DataFrame (logging from a simulation):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'runid'  : [26  , 26  , 26  ,  26 , 26  , 26  , 27  , 27  , 27  , 27  , 27  , 27  ],
         'time'   : [0   ,  1  , 1   ,  3  , 5   , 7   , 0   , 0   , 0   , 2   , 4   , 5   ],
         'process': ['p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2', 'p1'],
         'state'  : ['a' , 'a' , 'b' , 'b' , 'c' , 'c' , 'a' , 'b' , 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'c' ]
         })
```

Then pivot the DataFrame:

```
data = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['runid', 'process'], columns=['state'], values=['time'])
```

Output:

```
              time      
state            a  b  c
runid process           
26    p1         0  3  5
      p2         1  1  7
27    p1         0  0  5
      p2         0  2  4
```

How do I subset this pivoted DataFrame so that runid 26 and columns a and b are selected (so that I can subtract a from b for all processes with runid 26 and store these values for analysis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pd.IndexSlice` object to make the syntax a bit nicer, then just [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> data.loc[idx[26, :], idx[:, ['a', 'b']]]

              time   
state            a  b
runid process        
26    p1         0  3
      p2         1  1
```

Comment: Thanks! And how do I add an addition column 'bminusa' to this subset with the value of b minus a?

Comment: @Rene `sub_df.time.b - sub_df.time.a`? You should look at the [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) section of the docs.